# Node.js require fails to find module only when running in docker

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, discord.js

Edit: issue solved thank you @DavidMaze - [commit of the fix here](https://github.com/jNullj/Pikabot/commit/f240a30006a8af0e4886565f0f86bda35a4bce05)

While making an update to my discord bot i got a new issue, this issue does not happend when i run the bot locally but only when i run it in docker.

```
Node.js v19.7.0
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1093
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module '../database/birthdayCheck.js'
Require stack:

- /app/events/birthdayStatusChange.js
- /app/index.js
  at Module.\_resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1090:15)
  at Module.\_load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:934:27)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:19)
  at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:119:18)
  at Object.\<anonymous\> (/app/events/birthdayStatusChange.js:2:60)
  at Module.\_compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1275:14)
  at Module.\_extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1329:10)
  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1133:32)
  at Module.\_load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:12)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: \[ '/app/events/birthdayStatusChange.js', '/app/index.js' \]
  }
```

docker and local versions of node and dependencies of node seem to be all the same, so this is really odd. I also tried running them from the same entry script.

It seems the issue starts at this [merge](https://github.com/jNullj/Pikabot/commit/69c0d99c85142d77148faeeac32347f7906ee51e)
Full code available [here](https://github.com/jNullj/Pikabot)

I find it odd as there should be no change when running in the docker container.

Here is the code leading to loading the module:

firstly in [index.js](https://github.com/jNullj/Pikabot/blob/master/index.js#L52)

```js
// bot events handler
const eventsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'events');
const eventFiles = fs.readdirSync(eventsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of eventFiles) {
    const filePath = path.join(eventsPath, file);
    const event = require(filePath);
    if (event.once) {
        bot.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    } else {
        bot.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    }
}
```

This loads the event in [events/birthdayStatusChange.js](https://github.com/jNullj/Pikabot/blob/master/events/birthdayStatusChange.js#L2) which loads the module with the issue:

```js
const { isBirthdayCheckedToday, setLastBirthdayChecked } = require('../database/birthdayCheck.js');
```

and the module that fails to load in docker can be found [here](https://github.com/jNullj/Pikabot/blob/master/database/birthdayCheck.js)

What am i missing?

I tried running from the same bash file docker is running in the entry point but i got the same results, no issue locally only on docker. I expected the bot to run without issue on docker.

edit - more info:
Here is the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/jNullj/Pikabot/blob/master/Dockerfile):

```
FROM node:19.7.0

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    ffmpeg \
    build-essential && \
    npm install --production && \
    npm install sodium --production && \
    apt remove -y build-essential && \
    apt autoremove -y && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV DISCORD_API_TOKEN=

ENTRYPOINT ["./docker.startup.sh"]
```

And the [docker.startup.sh](https://github.com/jNullj/Pikabot/blob/master/docker.startup.sh):

```bash
#!/bin/sh -e

cat > botinfo.js <<EOF
// token inserted via docker.startup.sh
exports.token = '${DISCORD_API_TOKEN}';
EOF

node index.js
```

And [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/jNullj/Pikabot/blob/master/docker-compose.yml):

```yaml
services:
  app:
    build:
      context:
        .
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - DISCORD_API_TOKEN=${DISCORD_API_KEY}
    volumes:
      - media:/app/sounds
      - database:/app/database

volumes:
  media:
  database:
```

Comment: If this happens only in Docker, can you [edit] the question to include Docker-related artifacts, especially the `Dockerfile` and details on how you're launching the container (maybe a `docker-compose.yml` file)?  One popular Node-in-Docker setup basically completely ignores the image and stores the `node_modules` tree in an anonymous volume, which can be hard to update.

Comment: @DavidMaze Added the files, i trying cleaning the cache and my image includes all files on build and does not use any volume/binding so thats not an issue. i have ignore for the node_modules but i also removed it and it did not help. You can also see all project files in the added github repo in my question

Comment: It looks like you're importing something from `../database/...`; is that the same `/app/database` directory you're mounting as a volume?

Comment: @DavidMaze oh i feel so stupid, it was in front of me all this time, you are totally right, i forgot that the sqlite database is saved to the database folder, and i mount it. This should have been trivial yet i missed it.
Thank you for your help. you can open an answer so i could mark it as correct if you wish to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a comment you clarified:

> ...the sqlite database is saved to the database folder, and i mount it.

That is, this volume mount

```yaml
volumes:
  - database:/app/database
```

is hiding the same directory you're trying to import from the error message

```
Error: Cannot find module '../database/birthdayCheck.js'
```

The best solution here is to rearrange your application so that your code and data are stored in totally different places.  In the commit you link to, you move this `birthdayCheck.js` file from the `database` directory to a `utils` directory.  That leaves the `database` directory as purely a place for data, and there's no conflict with your application code.

If you can tolerate losing your existing data it would probably work to remove the container *and* its volumes with `docker-compose down -v`.  This would take advantage of a special case of Docker named volumes where, if you mount an empty volume over an image directory, the image contents are copied into the volume.  However, this only happens the first time you use the volume – in your case, if you added the source file in the database directory after there was already data, the copy doesn't happen – and it doesn't happen on bind mounts or in other container environments like Kubernetes.  This is technically an option, and it explains why this setup might have worked previously, but I'd avoid mounting anything at all over your image code.